# Google Analytics Goals

Tags: google-analytics

Is it possible to use events and destinations when setting up goals in google analytics, for example can I track this funnel:

User Lands on on catalog page
User clicks learn more and goes to product description page 
User clicks add to cart
User clicks checkout
OR
User Lands on catalog page
User Clicks add to cart
User clicks check out

So I can see if the user adds the item straight to the cart or clicks to learn more before adding to cart

So this means I am tracking the users destination flows but also how what they are clicking to get there, are they adding straight to cart from catalog page or clicking learn more then adding to cart.

Comment: You cannot mix destinations and events in one goal, but you can build segments with sequential conditions that include both events and urls. All in all this is a reporting question rather than a programming questions and should be asked at webmasters.stackexchange.com rather than here.

Comment: @dtreadwell Is your problem solved? http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

You cannot mix events and destinations in a Google Analytics funnel.

Workaround is to record virtual pageviews whenever the user clicks on the page. Then the whole conversions funnel data is available to you in Google Analytics using destinations.

Checkout the [pageview documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/pages) for more info.